# Eclipse on windows and Hadoop on remote cluster

Tags: windows, eclipse, hadoop, remote-access

Can someone please explain how to set up a dev environment for Hadoop on remote machine. 
Most of the tutorials online seem to be focused on local mode or pseudo distributed mode, which involve installing hadoop locally or through cygwin. I'd like to avoid this. Ideally I would like to push code to the remote cluster through eclipse without having hadoop on my local machine.

I already have a cluster and can access the file system though Eclipse - Hadoop Plugin, but how does one submit a job to the remote cluster ? What parameters in eclipse plugin should I change ? (I correctly set up namenode, job tracker location, but advanced configuration shows datanode directory, datanode location and many other settings).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the reason is to keep away from Cygwin and use native tools, my solution was to create a Virtual machine with a desktop version of centos6.6 installed HDP2.2 via ambari as a single node instance and all the native development tools upon the desktop. Once my code was developed I had a deploy script that pushed my code to the cluster, which executed in a CLI. The connectivity is generally assured with NAT or similar so it can be used on a work computer relatively unrestricted in full screen mode.

Having a native centos VM meant that all the code I was writing was developed on exactly the same version of OS and HDP as the cluster. It also meant I didn't have to deal with server latency when I was working on the CLI (it's mind numbing).